# ASP.NET Membership Password Recovery E-mail Customize

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership, password-recovery

I have an email template (`aspx` page) for password recovery.

I call it `onSendingMail` like this:

```cs
StringWriter _writer = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("emailPasswordRecovery.aspx", _writer);
string body = _writer.ToString();
e.Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
e.Message.Subject = "New Password";
e.Message.Body = body;
```

But when I added `<%Password %>` to get the password in the HTML line, I got the error:

> The name 'Password' does not exist in the current context

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

- Removed `onSendingMail` events.
- Created a new HTML web page and used `<%Password%>` to get password where I want. (Also you can get `<%UserName%>`.)
- Set `mailBodyDefinition` from properties window
- `isBodyHTML = true`
- And done.